# Getting past the painting puzzle

Tags: post-mortem

I've tried both to line up the circles like the walkthrough at https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=916963385:

[image: Circles from guide]

I've also tried to be as close to the centers of the hit-boxes I discovered sometimes appear when you click away from the window:

[image: circles and hitboxes]

In neither case will Hulot accept it.  He says one of two things:

1. Hold on, MacPherson, I see you've found mistakes where there are none...Do you take my artists for amateurs?
2. You have done well, but some of the mistakes you have found are actually ok. So examine them again, will you?

What am I doing so badly here?

If it makes a difference, I'm running the Steam version of Post Mortem on Proton 4.11-9 on Linux Mint 19.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there's a slight offset bug involved, *but that it only affects where the blue circles appear*, and not the accuracy of the game recording your click.

So the solution is to click in the centers of the above circles (or hitboxes) despite the fact that the circles may appear to be incorrect.

(The offset bug works like this: Under Proton I'm forced to run in windowed mode to be able to play the game; wherever the game window itself is on the screen is how much the circles are offset by.  So even if I position the window as close to the upper-left corner as I can, my window manager disallows the titlebar being offscreen vertically, and so all my circles are off by (0,22) or however tall my titlebar is.  If my window is, say, centered on the screen, the circles are *way* off.)